# How to edit my question to add clarification

Tags: discussion, meta

Where do I add clarification to a question? I was asked to better describe my problem. When I added further description in a comment, I was told it is not a comment -- that it should be a question. When I started to ask a question it stood alone -- not attached to the first part. How do I continue discussion on the original question?

Comment: Do you see an edit button under the question? Click that, edit the question, add asked details and save edits. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Any user who posts a question or answer on Ask Ubuntu or Ask Ubuntu Meta has the privilege of editing his/her own post. Click the small gray edit button under the post to start editing it. The edit link is marked by a red arrow in the below screenshot.

[image: edit link]

Click the *Save Edits* button to save your edits.

[image: Save Edits]